# Cannot publish mxd file using ArcGIS publisher

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapfile, arcreader, arcgis-publisher

I am having trouble publishing a map file using ArcGIS publisher. This mxd is intended for use by ArcReader but I keep getting a "file access error message asking me to check that the file permissions are correct and that it is not already open by another application".
I have been granted permission to publish on a shared drive and do not believe this mxd is being used by another application. 
Does anybody have an idea what else I can try to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have looked into this, but this may help you establish the correct permissions.

The files generated by ArcGIS Server at run time are only accessible by the account running ArcGIS Server. To change the access permissions of the files generated at run time (for example, server logs), you'll need to set the user file mode creation mask (umask) in the init_user_param.sh script. To edit this script, navigate to the /arcgis/server/usr directory.

By default, umask is set to 077, which means that no other users can read or write data to the runtime files. This is sufficient for most private ArcGIS Server systems.
    If umask is set to 022, it allows only the account running ArcGIS Server to read and write data. However, anyone on the system can read the data.
    Setting umask to 002 is a good option when the account running ArcGIS Server shares data with other users in the same group. Keep in mind that members of the group in which the account running ArcGIS Server belongs to can also create and modify data files. Those outside of the group are not allowed to create and modify data files.
    Setting umask to 007 completely excludes users who are not group members of the account running ArcGIS Sever.

You'll need to restart ArcGIS Server immediately after modifying access permissions for your changes to take effect. Keep in mind that once you modify the umask setting to a value other than 077, you have altered the access permissions of all the files created by ArcGIS Server at run time.

More information is available at: https://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/linux/common-problems-and-solutions.htm

If this does not work I would check to see that there is not other open application within the task manager that is also open and using your map project, even including the explorer.

Those are just some thoughts that I have on why you could be experiencing these problems. I know that ArcGIS can be very vague sometimes with the error message and troubleshooting can be a pain, good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My GIS admin guys managing ArcGIS Server are going to look into it and make changes if necessary. I do appreciate your explanation. Thanks again